# Write data in two columns at once from userform selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox in a userform. When a user selects and clicks an export to Excel button it exports the selected item to the 7th column.

I want to export that single selection to the 7th AND 8th column.

The current working code

```
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set addlist = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
For x = 1 To WortSelector.ListCount - 1
    If Me.WortSelector.Selected(x) Then
        addlist = Me.WortSelector.List(x)
        Set addlist = addlist.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next x
```

Basically I want

```
Set addlist = Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same variable name for two different columns.

```
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set addlist = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set addlist2 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
For x = 1 To WortSelector.ListCount - 1
    If Me.WortSelector.Selected(x) Then
        addlist = Me.WortSelector.List(x)
        Set addlist = addlist.Offset(1, 0)
        addlist2 = Me.WortSelector.List(x)
        Set addlist2 = addlist2.Offset(1, 1)
    End If
Next x
```

Hope this will help.

OR just make column 7 and 8 equal (after the Next x):

```
Worksheets(1).Range("H:H").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("G:G").Value
```

Comment: Thanks sdda, the second one works but when the user enter information in a new form it will replace the previous instead of going to the next empty cell and put the information on that cell. i really like the first code where you declare another variable (addlist2) i just dont know why it doesn't work, it does nothing at all.

Comment: Hi sdda, okay so now i modified your code just a tiny bit and it works what i did is just change the .offset(1,0) to .offset(1,1). but i really really appreciate your help very much. Thank you!!

Comment: hey, sorry, forgot the offset, you are right! :) Could you please mark my answer as solution?